# Email received without body and subject of the mail

Tags: android, jakarta-mail, sendmail

I am sending email through smtp but only file or attachment is received and not the body of the email and subject. Can anyone please tell me where lies the problem?

public class SendMail extends AppCompatActivity {

```
EditText edt_subject,edt_body,edt_choosenFile;
private Button sendEmail;
private Button chooseFileButton;
private String filename;
String uniqueId,subject,mailbody;
private static final int REQUEST_CHOOSER = 1234;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_send_mail);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    edt_subject=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_Subject);
    edt_body=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_mail_body);
    subject=edt_subject.getText().toString();
    mailbody=edt_body.getText().toString();

    sendEmail = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send_email_button_id);
    sendEmail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Properties props = new Properties();
                        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
                        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
                        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
                        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

                        Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
                                new Authenticator() {
                                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                                        return new PasswordAuthentication(
                                                "sender@gmail.com","password");
                                    }
                                });
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
                        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("sender@gmail.com"));
                        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse("receiver@gmail.com"));
                        message.setSubject(subject);
                     message.setText(mailbody);

                        if (filename!=null) {

                            BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
                            messageBodyPart.setText(mailbody);
                            Multipart _multipart = new MimeMultipart();
                            FileDataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
                            messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
                            messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename);


                            _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
                            message.setContent(_multipart);
                        }

                        Transport.send(message);
                        System.out.println("Done");
                    } catch (MessagingException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                }
            }).start();
        }
    });

    chooseFileButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.choose_file_button_id);
    chooseFileButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Create the ACTION_GET_CONTENT Intent
            Intent getContentIntent = FileUtils.createGetContentIntent();

            Intent intent = Intent.createChooser(getContentIntent, "Select a file");
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CHOOSER);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main body part needs to be first first body part of the multipart.  Your call to message.setText is overwritten by your call to message.setContent.  There's lots of examples in the [JavaMail sample programs](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home#Samples).